# expressValidator({ ^press\lib\application.js: TypeError: expressValidator is not a function

Tags: node.js, express, express-validator

I'm getting this unsolvable error and I am stucked with this.

> expressValidator({   ^press\lib\application.js: TypeError:
>   expressValidator is not a function

This is the full error report:

> C:\Users\Desktop\src\app.js:50   expressValidator({   ^
>                                                                                                    press\lib\application.js: TypeError: expressValidator is not a
>   function
>       at Object. (C:\Users\Desktop\src\app.js:50:5):3)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:829:12)
>       at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
>       at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)

I did whatever was suggested on some of the threads related to this error, but they didn't fix my problem.

Could someone please help?

This is my app.js code

```
var express = require("express");
var path = require("path");
var favicon = require("serve-favicon");
var logger = require("morgan");
var cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var session = require("express-session");
var passport = require("passport");
var LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;
// var expressValidator = require("express-validator");
const { check, expressValidator } = require('express-validator');
var multer = require("multer");
var upload = multer({ dest: "./uploads" });
var flash = require("connect-flash");
var bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
var mongo = require("mongodb");
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var db = mongoose.connection;

var routes = require("./routes/index");
var users = require("./routes/users");

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));
app.set("view engine", "jade");

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger("dev"));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// Handle Sessions
app.use(
  session({
    secret: "secret",
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true
  })
);

// Passport
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// Validator
app.use(
  expressValidator({
    errorFormatter: function(param, msg, value) {
      var namespace = param.split("."),
        root = namespace.shift(),
        formParam = root;

      while (namespace.length) {
        formParam += "[" + namespace.shift() + "]";
      }
      return {
        param: formParam,
        msg: msg,
        value: value
      };
    }
  })
);

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

app.use(flash());
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.locals.messages = require("express-messages")(req, res);
  next();
});

app.get("*", function(req, res, next) {
  res.locals.user = req.user || null;
  next();
});

app.use("/", routes);
app.use("/users", users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error("Not Found");
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get("env") === "development") {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render("error", {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render("error", {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: I checked the documentation and haven't really found the "expressValidator" method, that you want to use. What source are you using for this?

Comment: I used this source on github: https://github.com/VojtaStavik/GetBack2Work-Node/blob/master/node_modules/express-validator/README.md

Comment: Oh I see, this project use a 4 year old 2. version of the express-validator, checkout the latest 6. version - https://express-validator.github.io/docs/ , I mean I assue you have downloaded the latest version but use as the old documentation or the example showed you

Comment: Thanks alot. Yes. I was following a tutorial dated from around 2015.